# Odd Positioning of SKLabelNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, coordinates, coordinate-systems, sklabelnode

I am trying to add a `SKLabelNode` to the *top left* of my scene. Currently I am achieving this using a value of "300"

```
func addMoneyLabel() {
        let moneyLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Copperplate")
        moneyLabel.fontSize = 25
        print("CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),", CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
        print("CGRectGetMinX(self.frame),", CGRectGetMinX(self.frame))
        moneyLabel.position = CGPoint(
            x:300,
            y:CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)
        )
        moneyLabel.text = "$500"
        moneyLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Top
        moneyLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left
        self.addChild(moneyLabel)
    }
```

This produces an image that looks like this:

[image]

Why isn't "0" or `CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)` the correct value for positioning top left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the scene size is not necessarily the same as view's size. By default, scene size is 1024x768. As I can see, you are using iPhone 6s+ which has different proportion and different dimension in compare to default scene's size.

To debug this, put a break point, or just print `scene.size` and `scene.view.size.`

You can make a scene to have the same size of a view, if you set this in your view controller:

```
scene.size = view.bounds.size
```

Now, when you set `x` position to 0 (and set `y` to `CGRectGetMaxY`), the label will be placed in top left corner.